# Subprocess module not returning output when running command by opening cmd prompt

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using subprocess module to open command prompt and run few command in it and retrive the result.

I tried below code and it is not returning any output. Simply running for a long time.Please help what is wrong with this code. Similar to this code, i used notepad application path and text file path and it opened notepad application with text file. But command prompt is not opening.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', 'dir'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout=process.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `cmd.exe dir` doesn't actually run the dir command. You need to specify the `/c` flag, per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd). So you really want

```py
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', '/c', 'dir'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout=process.communicate()
print(stdout)
```